# Games on windows 8 in bootcamp lag even on lowest graphics

Tags: macos, windows-8, boot-camp

I've been playing Crysis 2 and Skyrim on my Retina MacBookPro (10,1) for months now. The two games used to run super smoothly even on nearly maxed out settings. This laptop has an Nvidia GeForce GT 650M graphics card inside, it runs great.

But I recently replaced my Windows 8 consumer preview with the retail copy, and since then, 3D games lag in this odd way, no matter what the graphics settings. Every second Skyrim and Crysis alternates between running smoothly and lagging. It's a cyclical lag that comes and goes like clockwork. I can turn the graphics down to 800x600 with no antialiasing and low texture quality, and it runs much smoother on the "up" motion of the cycle, but every second it moves back into this lag spike.

I've tried installing beta graphic drivers, reinstalling the operating system, reinstalling the bootcamp support software, and freeing up space (I have about 20 GB free). I can't figure out what suddenly caused this other than some obscure difference between the consumer preview and the retail version.

What can I try? Is my video card failing? Are there some other drivers I can install? This isn't normal lag from maxing out the card.

Comment: I have no idea what's causing this, simply by virtue of having not seen a similar complaint, but you might get better answers to this on Super User.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Suddenly, my game has slowed so badly that its unplayable. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Check out my ETA #2 here: http://superuser.com/questions/509934/games-on-windows-8-in-bootcamp-lag-even-on-lowest-graphics

Comment: If you find a way to downgrade the EFI or another solution, please answer! I still haven't got it fixed. No gaming for me.